# Simulate varying latency for network request in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to simulate changing network latencies (within a range) for different requests via chrome?

E.g. for testing what happens when the order of ajax responses differs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DevTools technical writer here. We have [network throttling in the Network panel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#throttling):

[image: Network Throttling]

But that creates a steady throttled state. As of Chrome 68 we don't have any feature for randomizing the amount of throttling within a given range.

You might be able to achieve this using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer).

Answer (score 2):

I think it would possible, creating an extension and use the [Chrome debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger)  and [Network domain](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Chrome/Firefox devtools extension that can simulate http request delay for configurable URL
[Chrome devtools plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-request-blocker-and/klhfgmmihbgojnnbhdbnefjmiidlgfld?hl=en-GB&authuser=0)